# Plotting unequal length discrete groups in R with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot some paritally sequential data by what's essentially a key value. Here's a sample data.frame to illustrate the problem.

```
testDf <- data.frame("x1" = c(26.7, 33.0, 23.6, 18.4, 26.7, 75.0, 52.5, 51.5, 56.1, 60.1, 57.7, 37.6, 32.1, 47.7, 65.7, 55.9, 29.6, 32.1, 26.6, 19.3),
"y1" = c(8.1,  3.5,  4.9, 24.6, 23.6,  2.8, 95.7, 93.9, 84.5, 83.0, 94.7, 74.4, 32.5,  6.7,  5.6,  40.7, 25.6, 16.5, 13.2, 22.6),
"x2" = c(33.0, 23.6, 18.4, 26.7, 75.0, 77.2, 51.5, 56.1, 60.1, 57.7, 37.6, 32.1, 47.7, 65.7, 77.9, 58.0, 32.1, 26.6, 19.3, 22.2),
"y2" = c(3.5,  4.9, 24.6, 23.6,  3.3, 3.1, 93.9, 84.5, 83.0, 94.7, 74.4, 32.5,  6.7,  5.6,  3.7, 43.3, 16.5, 13.2, 22.6, 24.3),
"event" = c(8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 44, 8, 1, 1, 11, 12, 1, 1, 1, 36, 8, 8 , 1, 1, 12) )
```

So 8 is the magic number here. I need to start with each occurrence of event == 8. Then connect all of the x,y pairs with segments until the next event == 8 (it's not important what the other 'event' numbers are, the 8's are the values that matter for filtering/reset purposes).

Put simply, there are four separate sets here. Rows 1 thru 6 are a set of connected segments; rows 7 thru 15 are another set of segments. Row 16 would just be a single segment. Then rows 16 to 20 would be another set of joined segments.

The Df might seem a little messy, but the (x2, y2) values for the nth row are the same as the (x1,y1) values for the n+1 row (except at the 8s). There is only one exception with a small, discontinuous jump in y from row 5 to row 6.

I tried to add a column that was an actual index (failed with 'rle' before using a verboten 'if' loop), use reshape to group by those indices, then use ggplot to make the segments. But I couldn't get the melted Df I wanted after numerous attempts. This seems like it should be easier but I'm kinda stumped as to how to properly group these before passing to ggplot.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you clarify what you are looking for help with (i.e. what is your desired outcome)? It seems like you're looking for a way to create an appropriate indicator variable to pass to ggplot's `group` aesthetic, but your last paragraph makes me a little uncertain whether it's the grouping you're having trouble with or whether you're getting unexplained behavior on the ggplot end.

Comment: So the answer below is the most straightforward, but your comment is also helpful. I was trying to use reshape2 to convert from wide to long. But wasn't getting the results I needed. I totally forgot about 'group' in ggplot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get an indicator variable for your groups by taking the cumulative sum of `event == 8`.

```
testDf$ind <- cumsum(testDf$event == 8)
```

This gives you the following data frame:

```
     x1   y1   x2   y2 event ind
1  26.7  8.1 33.0  3.5     8   1
2  33.0  3.5 23.6  4.9     1   1
3  23.6  4.9 18.4 24.6     1   1
4  18.4 24.6 26.7 23.6     1   1
5  26.7 23.6 75.0  3.3     1   1
6  75.0  2.8 77.2  3.1    44   1
7  52.5 95.7 51.5 93.9     8   2
8  51.5 93.9 56.1 84.5     1   2
9  56.1 84.5 60.1 83.0     1   2
10 60.1 83.0 57.7 94.7    11   2
11 57.7 94.7 37.6 74.4    12   2
12 37.6 74.4 32.1 32.5     1   2
13 32.1 32.5 47.7  6.7     1   2
14 47.7  6.7 65.7  5.6     1   2
15 65.7  5.6 77.9  3.7    36   2
16 55.9 40.7 58.0 43.3     8   3
17 29.6 25.6 32.1 16.5     8   4
18 32.1 16.5 26.6 13.2     1   4
19 26.6 13.2 19.3 22.6     1   4
20 19.3 22.6 22.2 24.3    12   4
```

Armed with this index column, you should be able to use ggplot2 to get the graph you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I've never used 'cumsum' that way before. Another arrow for the quiver.